integrate the following differential equation xy''-tan(y')=0
I need solve this problem but i'm really having problems
What i had done:
$$xy''=tan(y')$$
$$\text{use: }u=y'$$
$$xu'=tan(u)$$
$$\text{We will find } u=arcsin(Cx)$$
So I thought of replacing the u in $y'=arcsin(Cx)$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=arcsin(Cx)$$
$$dy=arcsin(Cx)dx$$
And after that integrate to find y.
Does this make sense for this exercise? I don't know if the method I used is correct

yes i will fix it

You seem to have got the correct answer, but I'm not quite sure how you concluded $u = \sin^{-1}(Cx)$.
We have
\begin{align*}
xu' &= \tan(u)\\
u' \cot(u) &= \frac{1}{x}\\
\int \cot(u) \ \mathrm{d}u &= \int \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x\\
\ln|\sin(u)| &= \ln|x| + C_1 && \text{for some constant $C_1$}\\
\sin(u) &= Cx && \text{for some constant $C$}\\
u &= \sin^{-1}(Cx)\\
y &= x \sin^{-1}(Cx) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{C^2} - x^2} + D && \text{for some constant $D$}\\
\end{align*}
This is a complete method, and I suspect this is probably what you did.
